# Retrieving pointer to an existing i2c device class

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am working on communicating with an i2c slave device using loaded /dev/i2c-1 master driver that is loaded and working in my linux computer. This slave device needs multiple synchronous writes as well as address offset for reads.

I have determined I need to use i2c_transfer() with an array of i2c_msg for these operations.
I have never written in kernel space before and I need some guidance on how to get **"Pointer to the device structure for the driver instance"** of the loaded i2c master driver on my system so that I can call the i2c_transfer() function from userspace. 
here is a link to some hints i found online about how to use i2c_transfer();
https://docs.zephyrproject.org/apidoc/latest/group__i2c__interface_ga540f88fd7f8f85eaad7872fe24a00267.html

The i2c_master driver is registered on bus 1 of my system.
The slave address is 0x6c and I can read/write manually using i2c_set and i2c_get commands from command line.

How would I locate the pointer of a currently registered device/driver structure within the system so that I can reference it to this c function?

Answer (score 0):

One method would be create a structure pointer (to the registered device type -i guess it would be struct i2c_client*) inside the i2c device driver and load it with the device pointer when the driver is loaded ( in the probe function).

The structure pointer should be then EXPORTED and you can access this pointer in your loadable kernel module. Use specific methods and functions to write to this deive (you should find it in i2c.h)

But the method is not really nice as any mishandling with this pointer can crash the kernel.